# Top new IT Security - Stack Exchange users for the week (email message)

Tags: discussion

Just a quick comment about this email message I received: in the email body (and in the email object) you talk about "new users", so I thought to find only newly-subscribed users in this chart, but then I see that all users are there. Then I realized that you probably mean "the new chart" with that expression :D anyways, this is not important, but I only wanted to know if I am the only one who found this thing a bit confusing the first time XD

Comment: Welcome, and congratulations on being a high scoring new user! Hadn't realised the wording was confusing, but glad you figured it out!

Comment: @RoryAlsop thanks! I must say that it's nice to be in there :D